# How to keep stack trace in Node.JS async function

Tags: node.js, logging, error-handling, stack-trace

I have an async function that I call from my router handlers:

```js
export const makeHttpRequest = (...) => 
  externalLib(...).catch(err => {throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err))})
```

The `externalLib` throws a JSON (not Error) so I wrapped it in a catch clause to convert it to an `Error` type.
Then in my router handler, I call this function:

```js
const myHandler = (req, res) => {
  ...
  await makeHttpRequest(...)
}

...

app.use(myErrorHandler)
```

`myErrorHandler` is an Express error handler that logs the errors.
But when I receive an error from `makeHttpRequest` the stacktrace display only the `makeHttpRequest` stack, without the router trace.

Why is it like that and how can I add the stack trace?

Comment: Your `myHandler` function will crash with a syntax error. You need an `async` function to use `await`.

Answer (score 0):

unimportant ramble: *I have the exact same issue using `node-postgres` (aka npm package `pg`). It almost seems to go out of its way to be untraceable beyond the client. Does exactly what you're describing too - passes a regular object as "error" instead of an `Error` or just throwing. I finally found a reliable way to handle this, but it's not very pretty.*

---

When defining your `makeHttpRequest`, immediately store the current `stack`.  Later in the function (in your `catch`) you can then log this with your error.

Example using your code:

```
export const makeHttpRequest = (requestData) => {
  // tracking origin as soon as request begins
  // no callbacks or promises involved yet
  const _stack = new Error().stack;

  return externalLib(requestData)
    .catch(err => {
      // I don't know enough about your code so I'm just adding what I do + what your original did.
      // Play with it if needed
      console.log(`error occurred - origin stack: ${_stack}`);
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}
```

**Please note** - if you have this async code running in more nested async code (further down the line - callback hell, promise purgatory) you will continue to run into this problem for the same reason (the callback gets fired from elsewhere, at a different time, on a different stack - no awareness of the stack that added itself to the queue).

If you have a very large number of nested routes and/or consecutive middleware, you probably want to also adjust how much of the stack shows.  Put this at the top of the function:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = 40;
// or ...
// Error.stackTraceLimit = 3;
// or ...
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
// etc.
```

There's also a Node flag for this if you prefer `--stack-trace-limit=...`.  Both are global for the execution context (Node - per process, Chrome - per window/iframe).  More info is here: https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api